# python program that writes on screen all the positive whole numbers up to a limit established by the user

Tags: python, loops

How do I create a python program that writes on screen all the positive whole numbers up to a limit established by the user using loops countdown?

This is what I have done :

```
limit = int(input("Please input a number : "))

for i in range (1,limit, +1):
    print("i")
```

Comment: Remove the comma after `limit`. Remove the quotes from around the `i`.

Comment: @jez still does not work.

Comment: "does not work" is not an error report.  Need to see what goes wrong, otherwise nobody can help.

Comment: just use print(i).

Comment: @jez sorry this is what happens when i run :Please input a number : 9
i
i
i
i
i
i
i
i
i

Comment: Okay Thank you @daniboy000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is wrong because

- You have comma in `range(1, limit, +1)`. This makes it range from 1 to `limit` with *step* 1 (`+1 == 1`), which is default. You want `range(1, limit + 1)`
- When printing, you need to use `print(i)`, not `print("i")`. `i` refers to variable named `i`, while `"i"` is just a `str` (text).

If you want numbers from 1, including `limit` do

```
limit = int(input("Please input a number: "))

for i in range(1, limit + 1):
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a stray comma in `limit,+1`. Change that to `limit+1`.

And `"i"` in quotes means the letter "i". `i` without quotes means the value stored in the variable *i*.

Putting that together:

```
limit = int(input("Please input a number : "))

for i in range (1, limit+1):
    print(i)
```

This will print all the integers from 1 to `limit`, including `limit`. (If you don't want to include `limit` itself, remove the `+1`.